# Fastest way to select lowest value in other table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have an index-table with trips people can book and a table with prices of these trips.

### Tables

**Trips**

[tripid] [city] [province] [country] [culture] [nature] [rating]

**Prices**

[tripid] [date] [duration] [price]

### The problem

When a user searchs I want to show the lowest price available.
I do this usign the following query

```
SELECT t.*, 
(SELECT MIN(price) FROM prices WHERE tripid = t.tripid) 
FROM trips t;
```

This works however it is slow. 5 seconds for 4000 results.
 Is there a faster way to achief this?

Comment: Have you tried JOIN w/ GROUP BY?

Comment: Can you explain? There is 1 row per trip in the trips database and multiple in the prices database.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your query is fine:

```
SELECT t.*, 
       (SELECT MIN(p.price) FROM prices p WHERE p.tripid = t.tripid) 
FROM trips t;
```

You need an index on `prices(tripid, price)`.  That will improve performance.

Without an index, it is possible that pre-aggregation would be faster:

```
select t.*, minp
from trips t left join
     (select p.tripid, min(p.price) as minp
      from prices p
      group by p.tripid
     ) p
     on t.tripid = p.tripid;
```

This only requires scanning the `prices` table once, rather than once for every trip.

Comment: I have added an index on tripid and price but even then your second query is 4 times faster. Thanks!

Comment: @user2740744 . . . The `group by` will also use the index.  However, I'm surprised that that approach is *four times* faster.  There are cases where your original approach is more efficient -- for instance, if you were only selecting a handful of trips in a `where` clause.

Comment: Well, it is some rough testing but it seems to be much faster. The trip table has 4000 rows and the prices table 1.7 million rows.

Comment: You are right. When there are a lot of results the second query is faster but for a few results the first one is faster.